# Echo count from data in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to count a specific field in a database that has user details in it. Every user has an id and I want to count the amount of users/ids that are registered in the database. This is my code, how can I solve it? Because it does not echo anything. I am not allowed to use MYSQL to retrieve the count.

```
include ("databaseconnectie.php");
$query = $db->prepare("
    SELECT 
        COUNT(id) as total 
    FROM 
        users");

$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $result['total'];`
```

Comment: `fetchAll` returns a list ( an array of array ). You just want to `fetch` one result tho.

Comment: If my solution solved your issue, please click the green tick next to my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way you fetch'ed your data, you will need to add [0] in the `$result` echo. (`$result[0]['total']`).

I added in a `print_r($result)` to show me the array so I could identify where the issue came from and how I can step through the array to get my intended result.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM users");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
echo $result[0]['total'];
```

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by @Federkun; you could change this line:

`$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

to:

`$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Then you wouldn't need to add the `[0]` as it is just fetching one result.